# Hide class property in result json

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, scriptignore

I have a class that retrieves a mongodb object, this class is the json output of my application. 
The issue is that I want to hide the "_id" field I can't get it done.
I've try to do it like that (I found in accepted answer here):

```
    [ScriptIgnore]             
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]    
    public string _id { get; set; }
```

But the "_id" property still show in my result.
I would mention few thing:
 - I work with .net MVC4 API Project
 - The mongodb item that I'm use is a child in the full result:

> {"response":{"data":{"_id":"51c38b14dc2ab62eb0265395",..... }, ..."version":1.0}

Comment: Kind of a side note since I don't know those annotations' functionality, but wouldn't it be simpler to just not fetch _id using a projection on your query if you don't need it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute instead:

```
[JsonIgnore]  
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]    
public string _id { get; set; }
```